# How to notify my other devices I when block users in QuickBlox? Syncing privacy list

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, quickblox

I can have the same logged to QuickBlox user on multiple devices.
But when I block someone and update my privacy list on one device - my other devices are not notified about this. 
So my privacy list is not synchronized between devices.

Is there a way or may be some option to notify my other devices or at least explanation why sync privacy doesn't work out of the box?
I mean it might be an option that when I update my privacy list on my iPhone, QBChatDelegate methods are called on my iPad too:

```
func chatDidSetPrivacyList(withName name: String) {

}
```